# cucumber with document form json in a feature file with angle brackets

Tags: json, ruby, cucumber

Does anyone have a suggestion on this example of a cucumber scenario:

```
When a "POST" on an endpoint of a webservice is issued with JSON:
  """
  {
    "from" : "<sip:+441111111111@1.1.1.1>;tag=abcd001",
    "to" : "<tel:+44222222222@2.2.2.2>;tag=xyz0001"
  }
  """
```

Now when I get this json in step_definition like this:

```
When(/^a "([^"]*)" on an endpoint of a webservice is issued with JSON:$/) do |arg1, string|
 puts arg1, string
end
```

The STDOUT of puts shows the correct string but when I use the html format, it drops the string under angle brackets i.e. the html formatter output shows:

```
POST
{
 "from" : ";tag=abcd001",
 "to" : ";tag=xyz0001"
}
```

I tried to escape the string, but that also does not seem to work and more over it adds additional challenge when making a REST call. Any insight ?

Comment: How would I do that for specific char in a string.

Comment: `code` 

    irb(main):001:0> require 'json'
    => true

    irb(main):002:0> json_string = '{"from" : "<sip:+441111111111@1.1.1.1>;tag=abcd001",

    irb(main):003:0' "to" : "<tel:+44222222222@2.2.2.2>;tag=xyz0001" }'
    => "{\"from\" : \"<sip:+441111111111@1.1.1.1>;tag=abcd001\",\n\"to\" : \"<tel:+44222222222@2.2.2.2>;tag=xyz0001\" }"

    irb(main):004:0> json_string.encoding
    => #<Encoding:UTF-8>

`code`

Comment: Don't put code in comments. Instead, edit your question, and add that information where you would have included it initially. Don't add "edit" or "update" tags to mark the change. We can see what changed if we need to.

Comment: When you view the HTML output, are you using a browser or a text editor? Browsers will think anything inside `<...>` are a tag and will hide them. You have to encode HTML entities into `&lt;` and `&gt;` for the browser to display them correctly.

Comment: Thanks @theTinMan